# Why is this model name not being displayed in Ember 2.5

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a really simple view that simply displays the name of an associated model:

```
<h1>Report name is: {{model.report.name}}</h1>
```

The router is simple and has a standard model method:

```
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('report-run', params.report_run_id);
  },
```

and the associations are set up correctly:

```
// report-run
export default DS.Model.extend({
  report: DS.belongsTo('report')
});
```

Report has a 'name' attribute, the value is 'User Report'

I can confirm that the AJAX call for the report is happening, and I can confirm that the report exists in the ember store, but when I render the page the report name is blank:

[image: blank report name]

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why the report name isn't being displayed?

Comment: Can you add the names of the files? cheers

Comment: The code looks good. Can you provide a not-working [twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com)?

Comment: Are you able to access name with `morel.then(model => model.then(report => {console.log(report.get('name'); }))`?

Comment: I was not -- you helped me diagnose the issue. The report ID was correctly listed in the ReportRun `belongsTo`, but the ReportRun ID was not listed in the  `report.reportRuns` hasMany relationship, so it was not associating the models together